# How can I save my graph by using host_subplots with a different size?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I saw lots of examples explaining how to save plots in a different size, but none of them was using host_subplots. I would like to save the graph as it looks like when I maximize the window which the plot appears at first. The following block is a shorter version of what I've been doing:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
>>> from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
>>> 
>>> host = host_subplot(111, axes_class = AA.Axes)
>>> plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
>>> 
>>> time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> velocity = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> another_variable = [15, 20, 25, 40, 55]
>>> 
>>> S1, = host.plot(time,velocity, color = 'r')
>>> 
>>> par1 = host.twinx()
>>> S2, = par1.plot(time, another_variable, color = 'g')
>>> 
>>> plt.savefig('my_plot.png')
```

And then I got the figure saved in a normal size!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`host_subplot` shouldn't change how the figure size is handled. You can set the figure size with `plt.figure(figsize=[8,10])` before `host` is created.

Comment: @Molly when I do this and run plt.show(), I first get a blank matplotlib window with the default size, and then I get a window with my data and the correct size. Is it supposed to happen? If I save the figure it works just fine.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating two figures by calling figure() twice or using a plotting command before you create a figure. If you ask a question and post your actual code someone should be able to help.